# Drupal 7 Field collecion, unexpected fields added upon editing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Expected behavior : after I have saved content that consists of several fields and unlimited number of "sections" (field collection of some fields and long text field)  and then I edit said content, I get exactly the same number of fields I had upon saving the content.

What's happening : after I have saved content that consists of several fields and unlimited number of "sections" (field collection of some fields and long text field) and then I edit said content, additional empty long text field is added that I cannot "remove".

Can anyone tell me what's causing this behavior?

Comment: It's a usual behaviour because if a user have permission to edit fields then he will get all those field even if it's empty.

Comment: The field is set to multiple?

Comment: @Adaddinsane Multiple is set to "Unlimited" if that's what you mean.

Comment: @RajeevK I do not understand why a field would appear upon editing the content if it wasn't there in the first place (I saved the content with one long text field, but upon editing there's two of them)

Comment: Then I would *expect* to see a new blank field. You filled one in and now it's offering you another. If you only want one, set Multiple to 1.

Comment: @Qweick I misunderstood. I though you don't want those field to be present where you didn't put the value. Sorry :)